# Why is my Collection<T> working differently to my List<T> class when copying?

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I want to copy a collection and add new elements **to only one of them** (not both).

In the code example below I copy the collection by creating a **new** one and passing it in the constructor. After that I add an element in only one of the  collections. After that both collections contains the new element...

```
var listOne = new Collection<Test>();

listOne.Add(new Test());
listOne.Add(new Test());

var listTwo = new Collection<Test>(listOne);

listOne.Add(new Test());

Console.WriteLine(listOne.Count); // 3
Console.WriteLine(listTwo.Count); // 3 (NOT OK)
```

When I use a List instead of a Collection it works as expected.

```
var listOne = new List<Test>();

listOne.Add(new Test());
listOne.Add(new Test());

var listTwo = new List<Test>(listOne);

listOne.Add(new Test());

Console.WriteLine(listOne.Count); // 3
Console.WriteLine(listTwo.Count); // 2 (OK)
```

In both cases I expect that the second list only contains 2 elements. Why is there a difference between a Collection and a List?

Comment: I expect that the collection constructor treats the collection you passed into it as a reference to the original, whereas the list one would appear to be cloning it (or just extracting the list items and copying them).

Comment: The documentation for each of the constructors explains this, in fact: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IList__0__ vs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__

Comment: The answer to your question is simply "Because it was designed that way"... But I doubt anyone other than a library designer would be able to answer as to *why* they thought you'd need a wrapper for an `IList<T>` which would be so dangerous (by which I mean, the following will throw an exception: `var x = new Collection<int>(new int[0]); x.Add(0);`) Ew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look into the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,35), you see that a collection doesn't copy the given collection's content. It just references the given collection as its own items.

The [list's constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,74) adds the given collection's items to its own items store.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. Still very confusing, because I did expect that when I write 'var listTwo = new Collection<Test>(listOne);' that the collection is copied... otherwise I would have written: 'var listTwo = listOne;'

Answer (score 2):

Because `Collection<T>` and `List<T>` do different things in their constructors

[Collection constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IList__0__)

> Initializes a new instance of the Collection class as a **wrapper for the specified list.**

[List constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__)

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that contains elements **copied from the specified collection** [...]

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `Collection` is very simple:

```
public Collection(IList<T> list)
{
  if (list == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.list);
  this.items = list;
}
```

`List` constructor is more complex, something like this:

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  if (collection == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
  if (count == 0)
  {
    this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
  }
  else
  {
    this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
    foreach (T obj in collection)
      this.Add(obj);
    this._size = count;
  }
}
```

This is because the `Collection` was created as a simple and flexible class. For this reason, it has virtual methods as opposed to `List`.